# MS Access: Can VBA store the results of a separate query in a table without having to run the query in the VBA code via a SQL statement?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, subreport

I have a form and next to it is a subreport. As the user is filling out the form, the subreport starts getting populated. This subreport is based on a query.

I want to submit one of the values that gets generated by the subreport into a table. Is there a way to do this without having to code in an SQL statement into my VBA code? Or is this the only way?

By the time the user is ready to submit, the subreport is fully filled out - I just want to take one of its values either from the subreport or the underlying query without needing to redo the query for that value (for efficiency reasons and whatnot).

Comment: Create a stored query conditioned on the form value's row id and run it on subreport update.

Comment: It makes no sense. A subreport lives in a report, so do you have a form or report or both? And a subreport doesn't "generate" values, it displays records from a query.

Comment: I made a form. On the form, I used the Subform/Subreport button to insert a section for a subreport.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a DAO recordset.  If you're creating a new record, it's a breeze, but if you are writing to an existing record then you will have to indicate a record ID, which from your description, you should have.  This link http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdaoadorecordsets.html may help.

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `RecordsetClone` of a form or a report:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.FindFirst "Id = " & SomeIdToLookUp & ""
    If rs.NoMatch = False Then
        ' Open recordset with logtable and add some fields to a new record.
    End If
End If
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: When I do this, I need to set a record source for the form (or at least that's what I read on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835062.aspx)). However, doing so blanks out the form when I put it in Form View....

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You have a subreport and a query, then you have a recordset as well.

Comment: Right but the *form* originally had nothing in the Record Source field in the Properties section. When I use the drop down to select the query that drives the subreport and go to Form View, everything goes blank. So the form is not dependent/takes no data from any record source, but the *subreport* does.

Comment: Well, it's the subform, not the main form, that holds the record to be logged or what the purpose of the copying is.